# Не учитывать клик по элементам родителя

Tags: jquery

Нужно получить клик `только по контейнеру`. Если я произвожу клик по элементам внутри контейнера, то они тоже засчитываются.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.container--top--music', function() {
  console.info('Вы произвели клик по контейнеру');
});
```

```css
.container--top--music {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px
}

a {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container--top--music">
  <a>///</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно проверять по какому элементу был произведён клик. Если это this, то блокируем выполнение скрипта.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.container--top--music', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) return;
  console.info('Вы произвели клик по контейнеру');
});
```

```css
.container--top--music {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px
}

a {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container--top--music">
  <a>///</a>
</div>
```

Comment: добавь пояснение что поменялось в коде и почему теперь стало работать так как ты хотел.

Comment: @Grundy поправил